# Continuity in the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, continuity, piecewise-continuity

The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus is as follows:

$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{x} f(t)dt = f(x)$

I know that to integrate a function $f(t)$, it must be piece-wise continuous. However, I'm not too sure about the conditions under which I can use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

My questions are:

- If $f(t)$ is only piece-wise continuous, will its antiderivative calculated by $\int_{a}^{x} f(t)dt$ have the same finite amount of discontinuities?
- Does this mean that if we were to differentiate this antiderivative as $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{x} f(t)dt$, the result would be undefined rather than a number?
- Does the differentiability and the continuity of a function carry over for its antiderivative?

Thanks

Comment: Suppose $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$.  (It need not be continuous, nor piecewise continuous.)  Let $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\;dt$.  For every $x$, if $f$ is continuous at $x$, then $F'(x) = f(x)$.  For other $x$ it could happen that $F$ is not differentiable, or it could happen that $F$ is differentiable but $F'(x) \ne f(x)$.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks, that helps a lot! Just wondering, when you say integrable, do you mean Riemann integrable? Would it be correct for me assume that the necessary and sufficient conditions for a function to be Riemann integrable are (i) that the function must be bounded, and (ii) the function should be piecewise continuous?

Comment: No.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function is Riemann integrable, but discontinuous at every rational.

Comment: [Volterra's Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function) has the property such that it is differentiable everywhere, its derivative is bounded, BUT its derivative is not Riemann integrablle.